# Border makes content inside li shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I select a li, I made a function so that the border is white. However, the border shifts the content inside the box a few pixels. How can I prevent this from happening?

```js
$("ul.quantity-grid li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.quantity-grid {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 50vh;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.quantity-grid li {
  font-family: "calibreb";
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.quantity-grid li h3 {
  margin: 10% 0 8px 0;
}

.quantity-grid li img {
  height: 60%;
  padding-top: 8%;
}

.quantity-grid li.active {
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quantity-grid">
  <li class="1bag" data-value="1">
    <h3>1 BAG, $35</h3>
    <img src="img/1bag.png">
  </li>

  <li class="2bags" data-value="2">
    <h3>2 BAGS, $45</h3>
    <img src="img/2bags.png">
  </li>

  <li class="3bags" data-value="3">
    <h3>3 BAGS, $65</h3>
    <img src="img/3bags.png">
  </li>

  <li class="4bags" data-value="4">
    <h3>4 BAGS, $55</h3>
    <img src="img/4bags.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also be able to change the `box-sizing` css property to `border-box`. This will count the border (and padding) as part of the width and height, keeping them the same when you add the border.

> The box-sizing property can be used to adjust this behavior:
>
> **content-box** gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set
>   an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will
>   be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be
>   added to the final rendered width.
>
> **border-box** tells the browser to
>   account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an
>   element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100
>   pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added,
>   and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This
>   typically makes it much easier to size elements.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 1):

Borders add to the overall width of a content box so it would shift the elements. You would need to make the non .active have `margin: 4;` to counter the 4px; that are being toggled in and out of the view by the border.

Answer (score 1):

Give it an invisible border

```
.quantity-grid li {
  font-family: "calibreb";
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

It has the advantage of not using your margin in case you want to use the margin for some other styling.

Comment: yeah normally i go for that approach to

Comment: This is probably a better way to code it.

Comment: yeah, this worked. sad i couldn't think of it on my own. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in these cases is keep a transparent border inplace for the inactive state and just add in the color for the active state. This will keep the elements in place

```js
$('ul').on('click', 'li',function(){
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
li {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

li.active {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> Item One </li>
  <li> Item Two </li>
  <li> Iem Three </li>
</ul>
```